# I am not able to publish my react app on github pages please?

Tags: github, github-pages

I am adding this in package.json

```
 "homepage": "https://ashishjaswal2002.github.io/Breaking_Bad",
  "name": "breaking-bad",
```

then in the terminal npm run deploy but still i got error 404 site not found

After running all these commands my readme is published instead of my react app i created
My Repo link https://github.com/ashishjaswal2002/Breaking_Bad

Comment: Is it still relevant? The site is opening now

Comment: But it is opening my readme

Comment: You probably need to run the `npm run build` command before publishing because your `gh-pages` doesn't contain the `build` folder